# Why does the weak/strong dance solve this strong reference cycle? I don't understand

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

Ok, I understand the reason for the strong weak dance.

One example being, let's say B strongly references a block, and we set that block inside B to strongly reference itself(B). We now have B strongly referencing our block, perhaps our block is allocated to the heap to run later (async perhaps), and our block is strongly referencing B. Let's say only some object A strongly reference B. If we kill A, then B -> block AND block -> B. Strong reference cycle and memory leak.

Another way we might see this is A strongly references B. B strongly references C. Perhaps C has a block property, and B says `C.block = ^{ self.blah = blah }`. Now we have B strongly referencing C, and C strongly referencing B. A is killed, and we have a strong reference cycle once again. Correct me if I'm wrong on any of this.

Now I'm seeing a strong reference cycle that in my mind should not be a strong reference cycle.

I have a class, let's call it A. A has a function fooBar. Inside fooBar, we call

```
[[MySingleton sharedInstance] doSomeBackgroundJazz: ^{
    self.blah = blah;
}];
```

We're seeing a strong reference cycle and A isn't getting deallocated. Now, in my mind, A does not have a strong reference to MySingleton. Maybe for the duration of fooBar it does, but the class itself does not. But when fooBar is done, its removed from the stack, and there is no reference to MySingleton any longer. Correct me if I'm wrong at any point here. Now, we know our block code that is in [MySingleton doSomeBackgroundJazz] strongly references A. However, why does this matter? A doesn't reference MySingleton. MySingleton strongly references A. No need for the weak strong dance.

However, when I put the weak strong dance in.. our problems our alleviated. A no longer sticks around. (Right now the real world problem we are having is leaving a view and coming back, keep creating a new view plus retaining the previous ones. Each one listens for a notification, and does an API call. So we can potentially have dozens of API calls going out every second).

Why is the weak strong dance solving this?

Comment: Question is pretty pointless without real code that demonstrates your issue.  It's certainly possible to do what you are in your snippet without creating a retain cycle or weakifying anything.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `A` is your caller to `-doSomeBackgroundJazz:`

It appears your `MySingleton` class stores your block off into a property.

Because you captured `self` (`A`) in your block, when the block is stored into a property it is also retained.

So this means that as long as your singleton instance (`sharedInstance`) is retained, it's block property is retained, and therefore your captured `A` is retained.

It doesn't matter that A doesn't retain the `sharedInstance`, it clearly is hanging around for whatever reason.

The rule of thumb is to cast `self` with `__weak` whenever the block is going to be stored into a property.  However it doesn't hurt to always make a `__weak` cast anyways, there rarely should be the case where you want a block to retain an object